# How can I prevent a Leaflet popup from closing

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have Leaflet popups bind to markers. My probleme is, when you click on a marker, it's own popup closes and I want them to always stay open at all time.

To be specific, I know I can use the autoClose option to prevent a popup from closing when clicking another marker, I'm talking about preventing a popup from closing when clicking on a marker that have been binded to.

I've been reading the Leaflet documentation and it seems like there's no popup option to prevent that.

There could be some sort of plugin to add options to popups, but I didn't find any..

Maybe I could create my own popup Class, and prevent it from being able to close ? But I don't really know how to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting both `closeOnClick` and `autoClose` to `false`? Can you run the snippet here to check if that's what you want?

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([38, -8], 7)

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
  const popup = L.popup({
    closeOnClick: false,
    autoClose: false
  }).setContent("popup " + i);
  
  L.marker([
    getRandom(37, 39), 
    getRandom(-9.5, -6.5)
  ]).addTo(map).bindPopup(popup);
}

function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```css
#map {height: 200px}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```